# Gnuplot, description distance to axis

Tags: label, gnuplot, axis

How can I get a fixed distance in gnuplot from the border of my graph to the description? When I use

```
 set ylabel "{/Symbol s}[MPa]" font "Times Italic, 10"
```

The description is a bit too far away from the axis.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there is the `offset` flag to the `xlabel` and `ylabel` commands:

```
set ylabel "foo" offset x,y
```

Type

```
help set xlabel
```

for all the axis label options.

Comment: It works for me, but I've already set a title for that axis, so I just used
"set ylabel offset x,y"